# LastAccessTime and get-date Comparison

Tags: date, powershell

I am parsing through a directory with multiple sub-directories and want to compare the `LastAccessed` time with the get-date time to see if the file has been accessed since yesterday, and based on that I will either delete the file or leave it alone.  I have tried piping the get-date results out to a text file and pull it back as a string, I have tried wildcard I have even gone as far as using the `-like` as opposed to `-eq` in order to get the comparison to work, but it is not properly comparing the data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
$servers="servera","serverb"
$date3=get-date -Format d
foreach($a in $servers){
    $CTXGPDir="\C$\ProgramData\Citrix\GroupPolicy"
    $CTXGPDirFP="\\"+"$a"+"$CTXGPDir"
    $CTXGPUserDirstoRM=Get-ChildItem "$CTXGPDirFP"|where-Object{$_.Name -notlike   "*.gpf"}
    foreach($i in $CTXGPUserDirstoRM){
        $datestring="$date3"+" *"
        $CTXUserGPPath="\C$\ProgramData\Citrix\GroupPolicy\$i"
        $CTXUserGPFP="\\"+"$a"+"$CTXUserGPPath"
        $file=get-item $CTXUserGPFP
        $isFileInactive=$file|select-object -expandproperty LastAccessTime
        write-host $file
        write-host $isFileInactive
        write-host $datestring
        if($isFileInactive -like "$datestring *"){write-host "$CTXUserGPFP on $a has lastwritetime of $isFileInactive and should NOT BE deleted"}
        if($isFileInactive -notlike "$datestring *"){write-host "$CTXUserGPFP on $a has lastwritetime of $isFileInactive and SHOULD BE deleted"}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your date comparison is deeply flawed.

`get-date -format d` returns a `String` representing the current date based on your regional settings.

`get-childitem <file> | select -expandproperty lastaccesstime` returns a `DateTime` object, which gets formatted as a "long" date/time using your regional settings.

To compare these two dates effectively, you need to convert the latter to the same format.

`$isFileInactive=($file|select-object -expandproperty LastAccessTime).ToShortDateString()`

`$isFileInactive` is now a `String` formatted the same as you get with `get-date -format d` and you can make a proper comparison.

`if($isFileInactive -eq $datestring){write-host "$CTXUserGPFP on $a has lastwritetime of $isFileInactive and should NOT BE deleted"}`

If you have to deal with timezones, you may want to amend it to add `.ToLocalTime()` before `ToShortDateString()`;